# The force acting on a plate of a parallel capacitor

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

How can you prove (using high-school-knowledge) that the force which acts on one plate of a parallel capacitor is equal

$F = \frac{E \cdot Q}{2}$

Where $E = \frac{U}{d}$ is the magnitude of the electric field beside the plates and $Q$ is the charge on each of the plates?

I can calculate basic integrals (although they're not in high school).

Comment: If $E$ is the total field between the plates, then each plate contributes $E/2$. But we argue that a charged plate can't feel a force from its own electric field. So it only feels a force from the other plate, giving $F=EQ/2$.

Comment: This doesn't convince me. 

Suppose we have a test charge (+) near the (+) plate. Then the most of the field is being contributed by the (+) plate (as the distance from it is much smaller that from the (-) plate and the electrostatic force is inversely proportional to distance, according to Coulomb's Law). Analogically, if the test charge is put very near to the (-) plate, most of the force acting on the test charge comes from the (-) plate. So why then should each plate contribute $E/2$?

Comment: Modeling the plate as an infinite sheet of charge, the field does not depend on distance. $E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_{0}}$

Comment: Yes, indeed, and the mentioned by you fact can be easily proved using Gauss' Law. Thanks!